# Изучение интернет технологий

Tags: книги

Вот решил начать изучать интернет технологии . Может быть я не правильно назвал термин, но под этим термином я имею ввиду: взаимодействия с различными интернет протоколами, серверами.

Если просто, то хочется понять как работает интернет углубленно, какие сейчас технологии существуют.

А также научится все это использовать в написании программ для работы в интернете и работы с различными веб сервисами.

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего лучше начать, может есть хорошие книги.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Олифер, "Компьютерные сети" (желательно, 4-е издание).